# Call async await in parallel with an indeterminate amount of calls?

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous

So I have an indeterminate amount of calls I wish to run in parallel in any example I have seen the amount of promises are known from the start.

```
await Promise.allSettled([someCall(), anotherCall()]);
```

My issue is I don't know how many promises will be required in the code below I might have 4 delays or 50 delays of various lengths however it does not seem to await for me any thoughts.

```
let qq = bulk([1,2,3,4,5]);
console.log('last');

async function bulk(array){
  const promiseArray = [];
  for (const delay of array) {
    promiseArray.push(bulkQuery(delay));
  }
  const valueArray = await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray);
}

async function bulkQuery(delay){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(delay);
      resolve('foo');
    }, delay*1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: You aren't putting the promises in the array. `await Promise.allSettled(array.map(bulkQuery));`

Comment: I dont see where you're [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) anything into the `promiseArray`

Comment: good spot still causes the same issue I have updated my script to show @about14sheep

Comment: If you need a variable length collection, use a collection that supports a variable number of elements.  You can probably find a suitable one [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-collections).

Comment: `qq.then(() => console.log('last'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it like this instead, there are problems in a way you write your function.

```
async function myFunction() {
  let qq = await bulk([1,2,3,4,5]);
  console.log('last');
  
  async function bulk(array){
    const promiseArray = [];
    for (const delay of array) {
      promiseArray.push(bulkQuery(delay));
    }
    const valueArray = await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray);
  }
  
  async function bulkQuery(delay){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(delay);
        resolve('foo');
      }, delay*1000);
    });
  }
}

myFunction();
```

by design your method bulk is also a 'thenable' function(returns promise). Which means execution inside the bulk will be as per async and await but any async method also returns a promise which means either you need to write a then or make an await by making this entire function as async await(as I have done in the code snippet)

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works, but only in the context of `bulk`. Since `bulk` itself is `async`, it's actually a promise behind the scenes, so you have to treat it like a promise!

When you do:

```
let qq = bulk([1,2,3,4,5]);
console.log('last');
```

You are not waiting for `qq` promise to resolve and you log `last` right away.
What you should do is -

```
let qq = bulk([1,2,3,4,5]);
qq.then(() => console.log('last'));
```